# Type definition string doesn't match number of bind

Tags: php, master-detail

I have an error in php and I have no idea how to fix this. By the way this is my school lesson example so I don't really know what's happening there. This is supporsed to be master/detail navigation.

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "base");

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM aeromiting WHERE id = ":id"');
echo $mysqli->error;
$stmt->bind_param(':id', $_GET['id']);
var_dump($stmt);

$data = $stmt->execute();

?>
```

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type
>   definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test1\detail.php on line 20 object(mysqli_stmt)#2 (10)
>   { ["affected_rows"]=> int(0) ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=>
>   int(0) ["param_count"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(4) ["errno"]=>
>   int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { }
>   ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["id"]=> int(1) }

Comment: Seems like you're mixing MySQLi and PDO.

Comment: The bind_param is looking for a querystring parameter, so the url going to this page should be something like index.php?id=1

Comment: @Kuya echo "<li><a href=detail.php?id=".$row['id'] . ">$row[naziv]</a></li>";

Comment: That's the code on the page that sends you to detail.php, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it in PDO, try this...

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost'; $db = 'base'; $user = 'root'; $pw = '';
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db.';charset=utf8', $user,     $pw);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

try {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM aeromiting WHERE id=:id";
    $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->execute();
    $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $totalRows = $query->rowCount();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
die("Could not get the data: " . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

Have a look at [pdo_mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) for more information.

Comment: This seeems to be better solution , but looks like I got this error **Could not get the data: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound**

Comment: Looks like we got an another error **rowCount() on a non-object** , I'm rushing to fix it by myself . I got to ask you , is there a problem if the page that sends me to detail.php is writen in mysqli ?

Comment: my bad... simply change `$totalRows = $query_rsEdit->rowCount();` to `$totalRows = $query->rowCount();` and you should be good.

Comment: Your welcome. That's what StackOverflow is all about. People helping people.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing APIs here. MySQLi can't accept strings or the likes as parameters.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM aeromiting WHERE id = ":id"');
$stmt->bind_param(':id', $_GET['id']);
```

Should be

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM aeromiting WHERE id = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_GET['id']);
```

This is of course assumed that `$_GET['id']` is an integer (hence the `'i'` in the `bind_param`. If it's a string, replace the `i` with `s`.

You should probably get a `bind_result` as well, so you actually bind the results from the database to some variables. Take a look at the [MySQLi documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Comment: I don't know , Im really new to this, Im still getting same error . But in what case can I use my example ? I'm asking this you because this was school example and code wasn't complitly writen and I assumed that I need to use MySQLi.

Comment: You can use either MySQLi or PDO, but you can't mix them. Your query is PDO-based, but you're using MySQLi-API.